# Prove $P(x)>0, \forall \space x>1$

Tags: real-analysis

$P(x)$ is a polynomial function such that $P(1)=0;$

$$P'(x)>P(x), \forall \space x>1 ;$$

Then prove that $$P(x)>0, \forall\space  x>1;$$

Comment: Great answers by all! but @rongordons answer was shortest and without much equations but just one argument. Moreover i got to learn a new term and inequality so, i hereby declare my acceptance of his answer.!

Comment: @seirios you was also great. I up-voted for you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: use the Gronwall Lemma and your initial condition.

Comment: gronwall lemma??

Comment: If $p' > p$ over some region, then $p> e^{x}$ over that region.

Comment: So do u say that $P(X) > e^x \forall \ x>1$

Comment: Hey gronwall lemma here is different. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall's_inequality#Differential_form

Answer (score 3):

Suppose there exists $x_0>1$ such that $P(x_0)=0$; without loss of generality, suppose $P(x) \neq 0$ for $x \in (1,x_0)$ (it is sufficient to take $x_0 = \min \{ x >1 \mid P(x)=0\}$, because $P$ has only finitely many zeros).

So $P$ is either positive or negative on $(1,x_0)$. But $P'(1)>P(1)=0$, so $P$ is increasing on $(1,1+\epsilon)$ for $\epsilon$ small enough ($P'$ is continuous). Therefore, $P>0$ on $(1,x_0)$.

Using mean value theorem, there exists $x_1 \in (1,x_0)$ such that $P'(x_1)=0$, hence $P(x_1)<P'(x_1)=0$: a contradiction, so $P(x)>0$ for $x>1$.

Comment: Why $P'(x1)==> P(x1)<0$??

Comment: @exploringnet: Because $P(x_1)<P'(x_1)$.

Comment: Because $P'(x) >  P(x) \forall x > 1$

Comment: @Seirios [P(x)>0 \ \forall \ x>0] creates the same spaces as using the [\space] command, saves you 5 letters ^^

Comment: Why can we assume $P(x)>0$ for $x$ in an interval $(1,x_0)$?

Comment: Because if you have $P(x_1)=0$ with $x_1\in (1,x_0)$, then you can take $x_1$ instead of $x_0$. In fact you take $x_0=\min\{x>1\mid P(x)=0\}$ which exists because the set is non empty (hypothesis) and finite ($P$ is a polynomial).

Comment: @xavierm02: I got that part, I mean why not $P(X)<0$ in such an interval? Is it obvious?

Comment: suppose you had $P(a)<0, a\in (1,x_0)$. Around 1, $P(x)=P(1)+(x-1)P'(1)+o(x-1)=(x-1)P'(1)+o(x-1)$ and we have $P'(1)>P(1)=0$ so you can find an $\varepsilon>0$ so that $P(1+\varepsilon )>0$ and $1+\varepsilon < a$. Then you would have $b\in (1+\varepsilon,a)\subset (1,x_0)$ so that $P(b)=0$. And you can't.

Comment: So, it is not totally obvious and your argument should be added to the answer.

Comment: I added some details so that the answer be clear.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Consider the function $f(x)=e^{-x}P(x)$.

> From the hypothesis $e^{-x}P'(x)-e^{-x}P(x)>0, \ \forall x>1$ or equivalently $f'(x)>0,\ \forall x>1$.
>  From $f(1)=0$ it follows that $f(x)>0, \ \forall x>1$.
>  Therefore $P(x)>0, \ \forall x>1$.

Comment: Very nice solution!

Comment: @Seirios: Thank you!!!

Comment: Good one! This was a pure bookish solution!